# Transform a matrix to two columns

Tags: r

I have a table with three columns like below

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 21 | 32 |
| 10 | 32 | 50 |
| 12 | 20 | 60 |

I want to transform it to matrix shown below

| Value | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Group 1 |
| 5 | Group 1 |
| 10 | Group 1 |
| 12 | Group 1 |
| 2 | Group 2 |
| 21 | Group 2 |
| 32 | Group 2 |
| 20 | Group 2 |
| 3 | Group 3 |
| 32 | Group 3 |
| 50 | Group 3 |
| 60 | Group 3 |

How can I do this in R ?

Comment: If your first *table*, I think you mean *data.frame* is called `df`, then `cbind(unlist(df, use.names = F), rep(names(df), each = nrow(df)))`. However, the numbers will be coerced to characters, which may not be what you are after. Could you explain what the purpose of this transformation is?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for `stack()`.

Answer (score 3):

With base R, you can use:

```
> dt <- data.frame(Group1 = c(1,5,10,12), Group2 = c(2, 21, 32, 20), Group3 = c(3, 32, 50, 60))
> dt
  Group1 Group2 Group3
1      1      2      3
2      5     21     32
3     10     32     50
4     12     20     60
> as.data.frame(cbind(unlist(dt, use.names = FALSE), rep(names(dt), each = nrow(dt))))
   V1     V2
1   1 Group1
2   5 Group1
3  10 Group1
4  12 Group1
5   2 Group2
6  21 Group2
7  32 Group2
8  20 Group2
9   3 Group3
10 32 Group3
11 50 Group3
12 60 Group3
```

Edit: to address the concern that column `V1` above is of class character. If, instead, this is required to be numeric, then we could do:

```
dt1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(unlist(dt, use.names = FALSE), rep(names(dt), each = nrow(dt))))
dt1$V1 <- as.numeric(dt1$V1)
```

Or, simply:

```
stack(dt)
```

as per the comment by @markus

Comment: The 'problem' with your approach is that V1 is of class character (because you use `cbind(...)`). Maybe use `stack(dt)`, see Ritchi's comment above. Note that `ind` is a factor column.

Comment: @markus thanks for your comment. It's not clear that the OP wants the first column to be numeric, though I suppose it could be inferred/assumed, in which case it's easy to just add  `as.numeric`. `stack` is a good call though !

Answer (score 1):

use melt:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- as.data.table(matrix)
melt(dat, measure.vars = names(dat))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way by using `dplyr`:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Group1    Group2  Group3
 1  2   3
 5  21  32
 10 32  50
 12 20  60", header = TRUE)
dat
#   Group1 Group2 Group3
# 1      1      2      3
# 2      5     21     32
# 3     10     32     50
# 4     12     20     60

newdat <- dat %>% pivot_longer(cols = 1:3, 
                               names_to = "Group", 
                               values_to = "Value") %>% 
                  arrange(Group) %>% 
                  relocate(Value)
newdat

# A tibble: 12 x 2
# Value Group 
# <int> <chr> 
# 1     1 Group1
# 2     5 Group1
# 3    10 Group1
# 4    12 Group1
# 5     2 Group2
# 6    21 Group2
# 7    32 Group2
# 8    20 Group2
# 9     3 Group3
# 10    32 Group3
# 11    50 Group3
# 12    60 Group3
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)

data%>% 
gather(Value, Group) %>% 
relocate(Value, .after = Group)
```

Output:

```
       Group  Value
1      1 Group1
2      5 Group1
3     10 Group1
4     12 Group1
5      2 Group2
6     21 Group2
7     32 Group2
8     20 Group2
9      3 Group3
10    32 Group3
11    50 Group3
12    60 Group3
```

Sample data:

```
data <- read.table(text = "Group1    Group2  Group3
 1  2   3
 5  21  32
 10 32  50
 12 20  60", header = TRUE)
```